# How to make sticky element remain fixed to top of viewport using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following simple navigation menu made up of 2 parts, a skinny banner and a topnav. I have used the `sticky` property to ensure the topnav is always in view (the skinny banner should not be).

However, how can I ensure the topnav then moves to the top of the viewport when sticky is active (to avoid the gap) - and make another adjustments such as reducing the height of the topnav (when sticky) using CSS?

```css
.skinny-banner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: $pastel-green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    gap: 24px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}

.skinny-nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
}

.sticky-container {
    position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  position: sticky;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

/* Just adding content that can be scrolled to */
.content {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.content-1 {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
.content-2 {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="skinny-banner">
  <ul class="skinny-nav-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="sticky-container">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content-1"></div>
<div class="content-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sticky-container {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: hi , I don't understand why you would want to change the height of navlist after sticky is performed? Do you mean you want to make it shorter or longer?
Because right now it looks perfectly fit compared to its font size.

Comment: also, which div is the "navlist"?
 the  .sticky-container or  .skinny-banner ?

Comment: so the topnav should be at the top of the viewport when scrolling down (to fill the space left by the skinny banner)

Comment: @cts cool!
  Did you test the CSS that I added to .sticky-container{}

Comment: Great thanks, it fixes the issue in my codepen! Doesn't work in my actual code, I must have a clashing style somewhere!

Comment: it worked in my codepen too !
Does your actual code contain other types of scripts?